# PHP Search for string then get next characters

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
blah blah blah
Team ID:</div>xxxxxxx
blah blah blah
```

where the x's are a 7 digit number.

How can I search for the "Team ID:" and then get the 7 digit number ahead of it?
(In php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). It accepts an optional array into which it will place matches. Index 0 will contain the entire matched pattern, index 1 will contain the 7 digits matched by the `(\d{7})`:

```
$str = 'blah blah blah
Team ID:</div>1234567
blah blah blah';

$matches = array();
preg_match('/Team ID:<\/div>(\d{7})/', $str, $matches);

echo $matches[0]; // "Test ID:</div>1234567"
echo $matches[1]; // "1234567"

$team_id = (int)$matches[1]; // convert matches to an integer
```

Be sure to check the return value of `preg_match`; if it isn't `1` then the pattern wasn't able to match anything within your input string.

Comment: It's working fine, except for it says NULL right after the 7 digits.

Comment: Try outputting your value with `var_dump`. If there's a NULL after it then the sample input you've provided doesn't match your actual input.

Comment: lol, nevermind. It was just some of my old code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't use regular expressions:

```
$str='blah blah blah
Team ID:</div>1234567
blah blah blah';

$key='TeamID:</div>';

echo substr(strstr($str,$key),strlen($key),7);
```